# Cloud deploy with multiple lines manipulate showing no curves

Tags: plotting, manipulate, cloud-deploy

I am trying to `CloudDeploy` a `Manipulate` with codes of multiple linesin Programming Lab. Taking a simple sin curve as below. If I simply use `CloudDeploy[Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n*x], {x, 0, 6}], {n, 1, 10}]]` , there is no problem and I can deploy the manipulate successfully. But I need something more complicated and I starts to split the code into 2 lines as below, and the deploy is a manipulate with button but the curve disappeared. How can I deploy the manipulate? Many thanks!

My current code:-

```
CloudDeploy[(
f[n_, x_] = Sin[n*x];
Manipulate[Plot[f[n, x], {x, 0, 6}], {n, 1, 10}]
)]
```

Comment: Shortly, add `SaveDefinitions` as `CloudDeploy` does not parse `Manipulate` when collecting dependencies. p.s. let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: Thanks. Get it done by `f[n_, x_] = Sin[n*x]; CloudDeploy[(Manipulate[Plot[f[n, x], {x, 0, 6}], {n, 1, 10},SaveDefinitions -> True ])]`